# Converges or not? $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2n+1}{n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2n+1}{n} $$

An answer sheet says that this is a divergent series but my computation says that it is convergent. What could be my error?
My solution:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2n+1}{n} = -3 + \frac{5}{2} - \frac{7}{3} + \frac{9}{4} + ... $$
$$ = ( -3 - \frac{7}{3}) + (\frac{5}{2} + \frac{9}{4}) $$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4n +1}{2n} - \frac{4n-1}{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{2n(2n-1)} $$

$$ 2n(2n-1) < 2n + 1 (2n-1) $$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{2n(2n-1)} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n-1)} $$
Because the right-hand series converges, my answer is 'converges'.

Comment: $ \ \frac{2n+1}{n} \ = \  2 + \frac{1}{n} \ $ . Hmmm... that series of alternating-sign $ \ 2$'s looks like trouble... (The alternating harmonic series part would be alright by itself.)

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you use the mathematical physics tag?

Comment: As you show, the sum after an even number of terms converges.  But the sum after an odd number of terms converges to a different number because the terms don't approach zero.

Answer (score 7):

The comparison test is for series of non-negative numbers. That's not the case here.

And your series diverges because $(-1)^n\frac{2n+1}n\not\to0$.